# WCF - Validate SOAP request before method executing

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF WebService on my server. Other clients are connecting to it with different environments (java, c#, php).

When user sends incomplete request, IIS is returning Error 500 withot any details. Is there any posibility to validate SOAP request and show validation errors to client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning on includeExceptionDetailInFaults in the config for your WCF service:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MEXGET">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: It helps! Thank you